# How to apply kernel tuning on docker container

Tags: docker, linux-kernel

I m building 3 different application container with docker engine v1.12 on the top of CentOS 7.2 operating system i.e. Nginx, mysql and mongo. I want to apply different kernel settings based on application and their respective container.

For example, I want to set `vm.zone_reclaim_mode` to `0` on Mongo and mysql container whereas want to keep `vm.zone_reclaim_mode` to `1` on nginx container. I tried to initiate image with docker `--privileged` command and modified kernel settings but its altered settings of host operating system and applied the same to all containers.

I already gone through many documentation and understood that containers run with host kernel.

I would like to know is there any way to keep kernel settings for container specific?

Answer (score 2):

Shortly - NO, you cannot do so if you're going to run containers simultaneously.

Why? Here is quote from first page of [What is Docker?](https://www.docker.com/what-docker)

> **Lightweight**
>
> Containers running on a single machine share the same operating system kernel; they start instantly and use less RAM. Images are constructed from layered filesystems and share common files, making disk usage and image downloads much more efficient.

Docker is nothing like VM with its own kernel.

Effectively docker is driven by host system kernel, thus all containers running at a time share same kernel configuration

Comment: Thanks for providing info. Is possible to launch container with

Comment: Suppose, If i launch container with custom build OS rather than pulling image from docker public registry. Can docker container allow me to keep seperate kernel settings for that specific container?

Comment: @NishantH You can store whatever you want within docker container. However docker daemon won't adjust kernel settings for you. Still, you can code some container launch wrappers, implement docker engine plugin et cetera